# Doxygen converts code span in heading to literal text (i.e. adding HTML escape to tag <tt>)

Tags: html, escaping, doxygen

For example, if I write Doxygen document as:

```
## Heading line with `code span`
```

The resulting HTML would be:

```html
<h2>Heading line with &lt;tt&gt;code span&lt;/tt&gt</h2>
```

It explicitly converts `<` and `>` to their counterpart HTML entity sequences, which literally reads:

```
Header line with <tt>code span</tt>
```

If I write this:

```
## Header line with <tt>code span</tt>
```

The result is the same.

The version of Doxygen I'm using: `1.9.7`.

Is this a bug? Or how to include actual code span in the heading?

Comment: I think this issue is related to https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/6998